# Luego de agregar una vista, en lugar de mostrarse la página de inicio de Django, el servidor devuelve error 404

Tags: django

Estoy iniciándome con Django y tengo un problema. Cuando tecleo `localhost:8000` me aparece la página de inicio de Django. Sin embargo ahora creo una vista en `views.py`, así:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def saludo(request): # Una función en este archivo es una vista de Django.
    return HttpResponse("Hola, mundo, desde Django.")
```

La ruteo en `urls.py`, así:

```
from inicial.views import saludo

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('saludo/', saludo),
]
```

La nueva vista funciona, pero ahora cuando tecleo `localhost:8000` me devuelve un `404` en vez de la página de inicio de Django. ¿Por qué?

Comment: Tenes que agregar el root path `/`.

Comment: Y por qué antes de agregar una vista no es necesario?

Comment: Y además, como respuesta a "/" que pondría?

Comment: Podes crear un index vacio, el clasico "hola mundo" o algo describiendo tu sitio. Deja de funcionar al modificar la lista de urls por defecto.

Answer (score 0):

Para usar path debes importarlo primero.

```
from django.urls import path
```